# Greatest and smallest value of a function in $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus, optimization, maxima-minima

Does the function
$$ f(x,y) = 2x+2y $$
have a greatest or smallest value in $\mathbb{R}^2$? I thought that since
$$ \lim_{x \to \infty} f(x,0) = \infty $$
$$\lim_{x \to -\infty} f(x,0) = -\infty $$
then the function can be infinite great and small, am I thinking right?

Comment: That looks correct!

Comment: A plane has no values, of course, so your title is not too meaningful. You're talking about a linear function whose graph is a plane.

Comment: You're right! Title edited now, thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does the function $ f(x, ~y) = 2x + 2y $ have a greatest or smallest value in $ \mathbb{R}^{2} $?
> I thought that since $ \lim_{x \to \infty} f(x, ~0) = \infty $ and $ \lim_{x \to -\infty} f(x, ~0) = -\infty $
> then the function can be infinite great and small, am I thinking right?

This is a plane and planes have no "values" of this type!
The calculation is correct but the meaning is not.

Comment: The OP is not saying that $\infty$ is an element of $\Bbb R$ (NOT $\Bbb R^2$, by the way, since the function is real-valued). I think your answer is not appropriate. Every calculus student is taught the notation $\lim\limits_{x\to a} f(x)=\infty$ to have a symbolic meaning; it does not mean that $\infty$ is a real number.